# Magento wysiwyg editor insert variable in static block not working

Tags: magento, variables, insert, editor, wysiwyg

When I use the editor in the CMS, I tried use the "Insert Variable" button in both show and high editor state and also edit html source.

I entered `<a href="{{config path='web/secure/base_url'}}/abc">Link to Base URL</a>`.

If my base url is http://example.com, it is supposed to chagne http://example.com/abc,
but it shows me the same `<a href="{{config path='web/secure/base_url'}}/abc">Link to Base URL</a>` in the frontend, how can I successfully get the true URL.

P.S. I got something like this in the 'edit html source' button: 
`<a href="http://example.com/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3tjb25maWcgcGF0aD0mcXVvdDt3ZWIvdW5zZWN1cmUvYmFzZV91cmwmcXVvdDt9fQ,,/key/68d29caa902f5d24dc08aa42aba1883e//denoate">Testing</a>`, but in the frontend it still show me back `<a href="{{config path='web/secure/base_url'}}/abc">Link to Base URL</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to add base url in your static block:

```
<a href="{{store url='abc'}}">Link to Base URL</a>
```

That should create a link to your store's base URL.

Comment: No matter what variables I add, after I update the 'edit html source', I saw it changed to `<a href="http://example.com/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3tzdG9yZSB1cmw9J2FiYyd9fQ,,/key/fb9e493a53fc7baa612f47073e5999b0/">Link to Base URL</a>`, but in frontend it still display in html code as `<a href="{{store url='abc'}}">Link to Base URL</a>`

Comment: Just searched a solution, in the template, I can use the code `$_myHelper = Mage::helper('cms');$_processor = $_myHelper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();echo $_processor->filter($contentToBeConverted);` to solve magento not convert variables problem, but I don't wanna do this to all blocks, I am going to find a way that if it is possible to do it automatically